# What’s this little arrow thing in the top right corner in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, operating-systems

Today I noticed a strange arrow in the top right corner in Google Chrome. I checked my extensions it isn’t and extension. What could it possibly be? A new update? I’m using the Version 89.0.4389.90

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate which version (build) of Chrome you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly normal, and is called "Tab Search". I personally didn't like it, as I usually don't have too many tabs open.

To disable it, go to **chrome://flags**, and disable the "Enable Tab Search" flag. Restart chrome, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I have the latest update, but I never use google chrome. So when I first opened it, I did not have the arrow, but Chrome was updated in the background. I opened it a second time and there was that same arrow.

So yes, this is definitely a feature in the newest build of Google Chrome. I am too on 89.0.4389.90 Official build.

When you press it, it allows you to search in your tabs or go to settings, so it seems to be a quick-access menu kind of button. Press it, doesn't hurt and will answer your question visually.